# Detect touch on OpenCV C++ window

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, touchscreen

I'm trying to open web-cam video and then pause it on first tap and then close it on second tap on a touchscreen display. I'm using OpenCV version 3.4.0.

Currently I can do it by either pressing `q` key or by *closing window* but I am unable to do it with screen tap. Here is my code sample:

```
bool exit_flag = false;
do
{
    cv::imshow("window", draw_frame);
    int key = cv::waitKey(3);
    if (key == 'q'|| cv::getWindowProperty("window", cv::WND_PROP_ASPECT_RATIO) < 0) 
    { 
        //do_something
        exit_flag = true;
    }
} while (!exit_flag);

cv::waitKey(0);
cv::destroyWindow("window");
```

I tried using `cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN` but couldn't use it properly to bring any positive results.

Pardon me if code isn't proper, I have created a sample for demonstration and I'm not very good at C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close your imshow window using mouse, you can simply use [setMouseCallback](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=setmousecallback#setmousecallback). Here is my approach: you can close your window by "q" keyword or by simply clicking to window:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

static bool exit_flag = false;


static void mouseHandler(int event,int x,int y, int flags,void* param){
    if(event==1)
    exit_flag = true;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Mat draw_frame = imread("/ur/image/directory/photo.jpg");
    do {
    cv::imshow("window", draw_frame);
    int key = cv::waitKey(3);

    setMouseCallback("window",mouseHandler);

    if (key == 'q'|| cv::getWindowProperty("window", cv::WND_PROP_ASPECT_RATIO) < 0)
        {
        //do_something

        exit_flag = true;
        }
    } while (!exit_flag);

    cv::destroyWindow("window");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. Code provided by you will work for the sample I provided. But I have detection.exit_flag instead of exit_flag where detection is a struct. Can you suggest how can I use that in mouseHandler? Struct has been declared inside main function.

Comment: @ShwetaChandel Maybe it will be better to ask it by opening a new post because I couldnt get the point and seems a different issue also.